# How to multiply layouts dynamically and know witch one is clicked by user?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Fristly, sorry for my english.

Then, I'm trying to develop an app with android studio. I'm doing well, thank to stackoverflow !

But now I have a problem. In my app, I need to create new layouts (from an original one) when the user wants a new one in the main layout.
The layout I want to duplicate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"> >

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="text1">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
              android:text="text2"

</LinearLayout>
```

After adding it and setting Textviews with data, the user can click on it to see more information (by maybe using another layout).

But the problem is, I don't know how to put a global Click Listener **AND** know witch layout added is clicked. I try a lot of things because it didn't work, can someone help me please ?

Comment: How will the new layouts be created? Programmatically within the same activity or the user is simply navigating to different activities?

Comment: See `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @NaveenNiraula Ok ! It's maybe that ;) ty !